# communication between two pc

Tags: ros, communication

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I have been running ROS core and other packages on one machine and subscribing to the topics on the other machine. Is there some way of limiting the amount of data received by the the subscriber machine? I notice that the master machine sends all topics over the connection even when the subscriber machine hasn't subscribed to those topics. Is there some way of limiting the number of topics that are being communicated? Thankyou.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157536/communication-between-two-pc/) by [AnuZam](https://answers.ros.org/users/11566/anuzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS does not transfer all topic over the network. It only transfers data for topics that are subscribed to.

What are you seeing that makes you think all of your topic data is being transferred over the network?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AnuZam](https://answers.ros.org/users/11566/anuzam/) on 2014-04-27**:
I had a utility that checked data transfered over WiFi (I had a WiFi router that was connected to just two PCs running ROS) and it was giving me data received even when I had not subscribed to any topics.